# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate

Tags: asp.net

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'Taste.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'Taste.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(PageContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(PageContext pageContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'Taste.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'Taste.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(PageContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(PageContext pageContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using `IEmailSender` in your `RegisterModel` which you should not, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.services.iemailsender?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

In general the error indicates a missing dependency, in your case an implementation for the `IEmailSender`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for information about how to register dependencies.